# Fxml controller, событие на checkbox

Tags: java, checkbox, события, fxml, scene-builder

Столкнулся с проблемой в самом неожиданном месте. Создана форма путем sceneBuilder и FXML и FXMLController. Есть неактивные checkbox'ы, которые по задумке должные заиметь галочку, если поля заполнены согласно заданным условиям.Например, если имя не пустое, галочка появляется. т.е.:

```
 @FXML
void registration_textField_name(ActionEvent event) {
String name = registration_textField_name.getText();
if(!name.isEmpty()){
    registration_chekbox_name.setSelected(true);
```

Где я туплю?
p.s. примерная форма GUI ниже

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Всё предельно просто:

```
@FXML TextField textField;
@FXML CheckBox checkBox;

void init() {
    // назначаете слушатель, который будет вызываться при вводе / изменении текста
    textField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {    
       // проверяете соответствует ли текст условиям
       if (newValue.isValid()) {
           checkBox.setSelected(true); // ставите галочку если всё ОК
       }
    });
}
```